# Developer Web Proxy

Tags: proxy

I need a proxy for web development debugging. Preferably something standalone so I can use it with both IE and Firefox. The one I have used so far is CharlesProxy but I was hoping to find a free one. Anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you: [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)
Very complete and easy to use.

Answer (score 12):

[fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) perhaps? IE goes through it automatically if its running, you have to tell FF to go through 127.0.0.1:8888 (might be wrong about port num, but its in the docs)

Oh yes, and you can also use it to generate http requests :-)

Comment: Current versions of Fiddler install a Firefox plugin, so using Firefox with Fiddler is as easy as clicking on the text in the Firefox status bar.

Fiddler is free, and tons of addons are available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need to do with it.

I found TrivialProxy to be awesome and very lightweight for monitoring what is going through.